# How to match java methods starting with Map using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following regex in `Python` to read a `.java` file and identify all methods but some are beeing skipped.

I am using the following regex

```
pattern = r"(public|private|protected|static|\s) +[\w\<\>\[\]]+\s+(\w+) *\([^\)]*\) *(\{?|[^;])"
```

There are some methods I am unable to match like all methods starting with `Map<...>`, for example:

```
    Map<String, RouteTarget> getRoutes() {
        return this.root.getRoutes();
    }
```

But if I try it on [regex101]
it is working. Why?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzzJN.png)

Comment: I assume this `[\w\<\>\[\]]+` expected to match return type of method, but it doesn't match `Map<String, RouteTarget>` duse to lack of space and comma in your class.

Comment: Also, I believe that generally, it's better to use some established libraries to parse source files. Have tried something like [javalang](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with regex:

```
(\w*)<(\w+).+> ?\w+\(.*\)|(public|private|protected|static|\s) +[\w\<\>\[\]]+\s+(\w+) *\([^\)]*\) *(\{?|[^;])
```

@markalex: Yes I did take a look but didn't understand it was the right pkg for my case.